# Как удалить определенный блок

Tags: php

Есть html разметка. Присутствует такой блок:

```
<p style="text-align: justify;">
    Фото взято с сайта <span style="background-color: initial; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif; font-size: 15px;">https://yandex.ru.</span>
</p>
```

Как удалить этот блок регулярным выражениям? учитывая то что сайт всегда разный, в идеале было бы удаление по **Фото взято с сайта** , и учитывая то что есть еще и другие блоки `<p style="text-align: justify;">` но их удалять не нужно.

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: Переформулируйте свой вопрос, вообще не понятно. что надо, что не надо! Больше инфы. И код. что уже пытались сделать.

Comment: ну дак и напишите `/<p.*?>[\s\S]*Фото взято с сайта[\s\S]*?<\/p>/igm`